# Adding time across daylight saving time in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dst

I have an application which manages appointments. I would like to schedule weekly appointments at the same time for X weeks from a known start date. I am using the code below to do this currently.

```
for i in 0..(events.to_i-1)

  if frequency == "Weekly"
    interval = (i * 7).days
  else frequency == "Fortnightly"
    interval = (i * 14).days
  end

  appointment_date = start_date + interval
  //Create new appointment here.....

end
```

However this fails to take into consideration changes in daylight saving time. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: This should take into account DST (at least since rails 3, probably earlier). How does the result differ from your expectations?

Answer (score 0):

you could use the since method in Time class and it will take care of the Daylight Time of Zone you are using.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-since

appointment_date = start_date.since(interval in seconds)

```
>> Time.now
=> 2014-10-03 19:39:31 +1000
>> Time.now.since(24.hours)
=> 2014-10-04 19:39:49 +1000
>> Time.now.since(96.hours)
=> 2014-10-07 20:40:34 +1100 (With Daylight Time applied)
```